# Recompile Apache in EasyApache to install MySQLi extension

Tags: php, apache, mysqli, whm, centos5

I need to know if I can recompile Apache using EasyApache to install the MySqli extension and my webpage and online system will still working fine.

I am using now: 
Centos 5.10 x86_64
Apache 2.2.26
Php 5.4.23

And the new version will be
Apache 2.2.27
Php 5.4.28

I will like to know if it's secure to Recompile Apache and Php without problems in my code.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to know that mysqli has absolutely nothing to do with Apache. It's PHP extension.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've recompiled Apache from EasyApache to add Mysqli and everything it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yea,only possible via EasyApache .

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.